# How to write Angular 2 (TypeScript) in one HTML file?

Tags: angular

## Introduction

I'm working on Blogger HTML template.

As you know, Blogger allow writing your template in only one HTML page.

I'm interesting with Angular 2, and i've found out how to write all **classes** in one **app.AllComponent.ts** file.

I'm starting with Angular 2 for a month, and i don't know about Angular 1 before. Reading Getting Start documents from the official page is making me to love Angular 2 from the first time i met him.

## My problem

Now aday, i'm founding a solution to write Angular 2 (TypeScript) in **script** tags on html page, to use Angular 2 in my blogger template to create an application?

But i'm stucking at how to config the **System** and implement **bootstrap** function to load my script, because i do not have an **/app** folder in my blogger template.

Is it possible to do that please?

Thank you so much to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a type of JavaScript library. So that we write angular code in html also using

```
<script>

</script>
```

tag.

In Blogger JavaScript plugin is also available to use JavaScript in page.

Comment: Thank you so much, but i'm founding a solution to write Angular 2 **Typescript**, writing Angular 2 Javascript isn't have a complete document so i'm not confident to using it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that typescript has to be compiled. Unless you find a way to compile the typescript into javascript and append it inside a `<script>` in your HTML, there won't be any way to do it.

So, my suggestion is to set up typescript where it compiles into an `app.js` after that, grab the file and include it inside a `<script>` tag.